# What can be the least possible value of data-compression-ratio for any real dataset

Tags: c, linux, embedded, compression, zlib

I am writing `ZLIB` like API for an embedded hardware compressor which uses deflate algorithm for compression of given input stream.

Before going further i would like to explain data compression ratio. Data compression ratio is defined as the ratio between the uncompressed size and compressed size.

[image]

Compression ratio is usually greater than one. which mean compressed data is usually smaller than uncompressed data, which is whole point to do compression. but this is not always the case. for example using `ZLIB` library and pseudo-random data generated on some Linux machine give compression ratio of 0.996 roughly. which mean 9960 bytes compressed into 10000 bytes.

I know `ZLIB` handle this situation by using type 0 block where it simply return original uncompressed data with roughly 5 byte header so it give only 5 byte overhead up to 64KB data-block. This is intelligent solution of this problem but for some reason i can not use this in my API. I must have to provide extra safe space in advance to handle this situation.

Now if i know the least possible known data compression ratio it would be easy for me to calculate the extra space i have to provide. Otherwise to be safe, i have to provide more than needed extra space which can be crucial in embedded system.

While calculating data compression ratio, i am not concerned with header,footer,extremely small dataset and system specific details as i am separately handling that. What i am particularly interested in, is there exist any real dataset with minimum size of 1K and which can provide compression ratio less than `0.99` using deflate algorithm.  In that case calculation would be:
Compression ratio = uncompressed size/(compressed size using deflate excluding header,footer and system specific overhead)

Please provide feedback. Any help would be appreciated. It would be great if reference to such dataset could be provided.

**EDIT:**
@MSalters comment indicate that hardware compressor is not following deflate specification properly and this can be a bug in microcode.

Comment: Are you aware that the compression ratio heavily depends on the data at hand? For example a 1 byte text file will be at least 45 bytes (if I'm correct) when zipped... Also, you'd have to keep in mind the file system specifics, specifically the size of a block to be able to even estimate this. The least compression ratio is the original data/(static overhead+the original data) in case of uncompressible data...

(Just a story: A friend of mine once thought about a compression with a brilliant compression ratio: it would compress everything into 1 byte, and then always extract Microsoft Excel...)

Comment: @ppeterka66 :thanks,I am aware of what you said. if we use deflate, an zero byte empty file compressed into 2 bytes and 6 byte "header+footer" makes it total 8 bytes which give zero data compression ratio :)  I am not concern with header,footer, extremely small dataset and system specific details as i am separately handling that. what i am particularly concern is, real data with minimum size of 1K and which can provide compression ratio less than "0.99"

Comment: @raj_gt1: Please update your question to discuss your _actual_ situation.  You have tried to cast your real problem into an abstract one dealing with the deflate format.  That question does not have a useful answer, since the lower limit on the compression ratio as you have defined it is zero, assuming that the only constraint is the deflate format.

Comment: Compressing a random 1024-byte chunk of data, for example from `/dev/urandom` or other good PRNG like Xorshift, typically produces a deflated block of about 1072 bytes, yielding a deflate compression ratio of 0.96 of less. This shows that ~ 0.96 is *common*. You can find worse compression ratios in already compressed data. These are all common; the pathological cases that produce much worse compressions are rarer.

Comment: My survey on compression http://goo.gl/2okQWR (see Section 2.2) shows that most practical techniques on real datasets achieve compression ratio ~2X and some upto 4X, although potential for 16X exists. Techniques with higher ratio have high overhead too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deflate algorithm has a similar approach as the ZLIB algorithm. It uses a 3 bit header, and the lower two bits are `00` when the following block is stored length-prefixed but otherwise uncompressed.

This means the worst case is an one byte input that blows up to 6 bytes (3 bits header, 32 bits length, 8 bits data, 5 bits padding), so the worst ratio is 1/6 = 0.16.

This is of course assuming an optimal encoder. A suboptimal encoder would transmit an Huffman table for that one byte.

Comment: What if there is constrain that minimum data in dataset should be 1K as indicated in question.if we use deflate, a zero byte empty file compressed into 2 bytes and 6 byte "header+footer" makes it total 8 bytes which give zero data compression ratio. so even practically, minimum compression ratio is "zero(0/2)" and not "0.2". As i said in question i am handling this cases separately including case of extremely small dataset. Also giving 5X space would not be feasible where I don't know any case where 1K bytes compressing into 5K bytes. hope you understand my point.

Comment: @raj_gt1: A zero byte input file can be compressed using zero deflate blocks, so header sizes are irrelevant. And 0/0 is properly undefined. Also, you trivially have a worst case for 1024 bytes input, namely 1029 bytes output.

Comment: this is what "ZLIB" does but in my API i can not use this method of returning original data plus 5 byte header. I must have to return actual "compressed" data which can be more than 1029 bytes (though you can not produce it using `ZLIB` as it do not compress in this situation and return uncompressed data back).

Comment: @raj_gt1: Sorry, I don't follow you. The process I describe is how the deflate compression algorithm is defined. It's not ZLIB specific. If your algorithm is not deflate, but something else, you'll have to tell us.

Comment: thanks for clearing confusion..however hardware compressor following deflate in specification but for this particular case it is returning actual compressed data instead of original plus 5 byte header.Seems like a hardware bug,I will forward it to vendor. For now what i can do is to do it in software,whenever such case occur.

Comment: Actually, it can be arbitrarily worse than a one-byte stored block, since there is nothing in the format that prevents empty stored blocks.  In fact empty stored blocks are produce by deflate as sync markers.  Though no sane compressor would output lots of empty stored blocks, unless requested.  BTW, zlib uses exactly the deflate approach since it uses deflate.

Comment: A one-byte stored block takes six bytes, not five, giving 1/6 instead of 1/5.

Comment: A sane compressor will use a static block for a single byte instead of a stored block.  That will only take 3 bits + 9 bits + 8 bits = 20 bits or three bytes -- less than the six bytes for a one-byte stored block.  So 1/3 instead of 1/6.

Comment: A zero byte input cannot be compressed with zero deflate blocks.  You must have a final block, which can be a 10-bit empty static block, which will take two bytes.

Answer (score 3):

because the pigeon priciple

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

you will always have strings that get compressed and strings that get expanded

http://matt.might.net/articles/why-infinite-or-guaranteed-file-compression-is-impossible/

theoretically you can achieve best compression with 0 entropy data (infinite compression ratio) and worst compression with infinite entropy data (AWGN noise, so you have 0 compression ratio).

Comment: So "theoretically" compression ratio can be zero to infinite. I am more interested in practically least possible value of compression ratio as i can not provide infinite space in my API..:) I have edited the question to make this point. listed articles are good. thanks for that.

Comment: @raj_gt1: No, that is an incorrect conclusion. This answer is stating the obvious, and does not help answer your question at all. For instance, since it is so generic it also applies to the ZLIB method with the 5 byte prefix/64kB uncompressed data, which clearly has a compression ratio of almost one (0.996) even for data with infinite entropy. The claimed lower bound of 0 means that the compressed data can be any finite size regardless of the input size.

Comment: the short answer is that you cannot tell the outcome (i.e. the final size) until you run the algorithm; it's much like when you use an hash function: you have to run it to get the digest. So computing the final size means executing the compression algorithm over the data. Actually, your "closed-form formula" to know the final size IS the compression algorithm.

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question: what is the lower bound? You are just repeating the fact that the exact result depends on the exact input, which is already implied by the need for a lower bound.

Comment: the lower bound expressed in bytes depends on the actual implementation, it could be 10 bytes, 20 bytes... whatever... do we have an header? how much large is the header? with classic RLE (Run Length Encoding) the lower bound is 0 bytes (i.e. we compress a 0 bytes file)

Comment: however your question is ambiguous. What do you mean with "real dataset"? Any dataset can be "real", it depends on the particular scenario... To me even 1024 bytes coming out from a PRNG could be a real dataset (imagine a Truecrypt volume). So there's no such lower bound but only a specific value of compression ratio for every dataset. With RLE I could be tempted to tell you that a very long sequence of 0xAA bytes will get compressed with a very high compression ratio. However, does this sequence is a real dataset? How about an infinite one? (i.e. infinite compression ratio?)

Comment: @G_G: the question specifically mentions _deflate_, and we're not looking for an upper bound (which is ~11000 for _deflate, 32 KB backref in 3 bytes). The lower bound is similarly well-defined. It is defined as the lowest ratio across all possible strings (so 2^N for an N bit string).

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell from your question whether you're using zlib or not.  If you're using zlib, it provides a function, [`deflateBound()`](http://zlib.net/manual.html#Advanced), which does exactly what you're asking for, taking an uncompressed size and returning the maximum compressed size.  It takes into account how the deflate stream was initialized with `deflateInit()` or `deflateInit2()` in computing the proper header and trailer sizes.

If you're writing your own deflate, then you will already know what the maximum compressed size is based on how often you allow it to use stored blocks.

*Update:*  The only way to know for sure the maximum data expansion of a hardware deflator is to obtain the algorithm used.  Then through inspection you can determine how often it will emit stored blocks for random data.

The only alternative is empirical and unreliable.  You can feed the hardware compressor random data, and examine the results.  You can use [infgen](http://zlib.net/infgen.c.gz) to disassemble the deflate output and see the stored blocks and their sizes.  Then you can write a linear bounding formula for the expansion.  Then add some margin to the additive and multiplicative terms to cover for situations that you did not observe in your tests.

This will only work if the hardware deflate algorithm is well behaved, which means that it will not write a fixed or dynamic deflate block if a stored block would be smaller.  If it is not well behaved, then all bets are off.

Comment: thanks, I am not using ZLIB but writing a zlib like API for an on chip compressor which usage deflate.

Comment: thanks for the update. As hardware compressor do not generate non-compressed block so Now i am planing to handle this situation in software when compressed data length is more than uncompressed data. As the situation is rare it should not give much performance penalty and reliability will be ensured too.

Comment: For a specific algorithm you can usually work out by inspection the sort of file that will cause it trouble. My suggestion would be "fullfile" which was designed ages ago to break the realtime compressors on some acoustic modems. Essentially start with equal numbers of every byte in a largish file and shuffle them up until the histogram for 2 and 3 byte patterns is flat. That should be enough to break most deflate algorithms. In 1024 length you can also avoid having any useable length sequence repeats available.