# C# Limit image size under 150kb

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, file

We have created a software in windows c# for cropping image as per the mouse drawn rectangle.

The images are of various dimensions and filesize.

**When the user will save the image we want to keep the filesize under 150Kb.**

For any file over 150kb 
We are compressing the images while saving using image interpolation mode.

If still the size is above 150kb the next step we want is to to reduce file dimensions proportionally until it's under 150 kB.

***We have created a loop to reduce the image dimensions by 5 percent and then we save the file and check size and continue until the 150kb.***

As we will be working on very high number of images want to confirm if this is the right way of doing it? Or someone from stack overflow suggest a better method.

*Will share the code if required.*

P.S.
saving image each time just to check the size doesn't feel correct.

Comment: How else are you going to determine the encoded image size if you don't fully encode it (at which point you have already saved it, in the memory stream / byte array)? Other than that, make sure that your resize loop each time resizes the original image rather then the previously resized one, and potentially change your 5% approach to be something more clever (binary search? size prediction based on the bitmap size and average compression provided by the file format?).

Comment: @GSerg I read "save" as "save to disk". In this case your comment on saving the image "only" in a memory stream/byte array, is actually the part that keeps the performance up, compared to writing the data to disk as well.

Comment: Thanks saving it to memory makes it much faster.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just to calculate image size yourself. Knowing format compression and dimension you could more or less predict size of image. You could check this link as an [example](https://toolstud.io/photo/megapixel.php?width=1080&height=1920&compare=photo&calculate=compressed#calculate)

Comment: The tool is really helpful.

Comment: Any such tool available to add to my project which does this work automatically

Comment: I am not aware of exiting libraries. But i think it is just a formula you need to adopt into your project. You can check some information in similar  [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280125/is-there-some-way-to-predict-png-size). Or maybe you can take a look on source code of website i've posted above and get idea how does it work.